# Laravel 5 How to store the Publish Timestamps when user click the Publish Button

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi is there a way to store publish timestamps when user click the publish button for their post?

There are three buttons in a post: Draft Button, Publish Button, Pending Button.
When a user is creating a post, he can choose either the draft, publish or pending button.

Here if the user click the Publish Button, i want to store the timestamp the user click the Publish Button.

Comment: What is your table structure in DB?

Comment: Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('subject');
            $table->string('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can store the current timestamp in our Data base. 
In your controller you can get the current date and time  by

```
    $dateTime=date('Y-m-d H:i');
```

then store $dateTime in you table.

Comment: by default we had created two timestamps. once is created timestamps and other is updated timestamps. What i need is when we press publish button, it will store the other column called publish_timestamps. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Hi Dev are you storing the data on change if so then you can do this in table only by adding "ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" to our 'publish_timestamps' column it will automatically store the timestamp of publish button click.

Answer (score 0):

You can create another 1 field `activ` or `enabled`

```
  $table
            ->boolean('enabled')
            ->default(false)
            ->after('body');
```

And at the click of a button write to it true, then print all your publications:

```
Post::whereEnabled(true);
```

Timestamp:

```
Post->updated_at->format('d.m.Y');
```